# How to inject properties from multiple property placeholders into java

Tags: spring, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

In my camel/blueprint project i defined a `property-placeholder` in the blueprint.xml:

```
<cm:property-placeholder id="props.placeholder" persistent-id="props.blueprint">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="app.name" value="app-service" />
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>
```

With this in place i can inject the properties in java (e.g. camel routes):

```
@Value("${app.name}")
private String name;
```

Now i need to introduce a 2nd property placeholder:

```
<cm:property-placeholder id="container_specific.placeholder" persistent-id="container_specific.blueprint"
                         placeholder-prefix="%%{" placeholder-suffix="}%%">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="service.port" value="1234"/>
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>
```

But how to use/inject property from the 2nd holder into java? `@Value("%%{service.port}%%)` does not work.

Comment: Did you try @PropertyInject("{{service.port}}"))

Comment: how is this related to the 2nd placeholder?

Comment: I mean replace the @Value annotation with @PropertyInject("service.port"), I have used it in my code this way and that works. The main use I would think of different property-placeholder is when you are doing unit tests and you want to override them in your tests. Then you refer to the persisent-id value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

There is an example which shows how to refer to the blueprint by id, so just configure Camel to refer to those two ids

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" 
                     location="blueprint:props.placeholder,blueprint:container_specific.placeholder">
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this work with ``@Value("${app.name}")`` or do i need to use ``@PropertyInject``? What will happen with ambiguous property names?